# Where to create a common file to all users on Android

Tags: android, file, csv, directory

I am developing an Android app on a tablet that would be given to bring home by users.The tablet has the administrator account and it has a restricted user account. I have a csv file that is updated by the administrator. This csv file contains user Ids. When the app loads, it reads the csv file and prompts the user to enter his.
When the app finished a loop, it saves the data on to an other csv file to be retrieved bu the administrator.
The problem is that I am unable to find a path on the android tree that is accessible from the administrator and form the user account. Furthermore, I also need to access the results when the tablet is plugged to a computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a file to be accessible by all the users on the tablet, you need to place the file in the sdcard/Android/obb folder.